# Order of operations with math calculation is wrong without parenthesise

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm running a simple calculation on a table and have noticed something really strange happening.

```
COALESCE(Quantity, 0) as TotalQuantity,
COALESCE(ToSiteTotal, 0) ToSiteTotal,
COALESCE(FromSite, 0) FromSite,
COALESCE(Transfer, 0)  Transfer,
COALESCE(ToSiteTotal, 0) - COALESCE(FromSite, 0) + COALESCE(Transfer, 0) TotalAtSite,
```

These values give me the values: 281, 301, 33, 0, 268 respectively

I then have a case statement further down in my query that drops into an else statement where I have to find the difference between two of the columns above:

```
...
ELSE 
    COALESCE(Quantity, 0) -
    COALESCE(ToSiteTotal, 0) - COALESCE(FromSite, 0) + COALESCE(Transfer, 0)    
END
```

When I run this to calculate what is not at site (I've confirmed it's falling into this else statement), I get -53 as an answer.  However, if I wrap the second line of the else in parantheses, like this:

```
...
ELSE 
    COALESCE(Quantity, 0) -
    (COALESCE(ToSiteTotal, 0) - COALESCE(FromSite, 0) + COALESCE(Transfer, 0))  
END
```

I get the expected value of 13.

Why would this be happening.  Is there some sort of order of operations that T-SQL does that I am not aware of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Runs as expected for both sets.

281 - 301 - 33 - 0 is and should be -53. Left to right, the first thing that happens is 281 - 301, and you're already negative. Subtract another 33 and there you go.

If you want the stuff to right to all happen together, you should expect to need parentheses. Moving it to another line means nothing.
281 - (301 - 33 - 0) is 13.

Comment: My goodness. I need to go to bed.  I've been staring at this for the past two hours and it was staring me in the face the whole time.  Thank you.